# Defuse journey event when coupons are sold out

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, data

IM sending an invitation with a Coupon and I have configured 2 splits if the user didn't opened previous mail, how can I avoid sending all the reminders if my coupons sold out earlier?

I don't know how to validate if there isn't any coupons stop sending reminder

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Below is the approach you can follow to achieve this -

1. Create a data extension with one field called "Available Coupon Count" and this DE has to be updated either by automation using SQL or any other process being used to identify that the coupon is sold out.
2. Add the above DE to attribute groups so that it can be accessed via "Decision Split" activity in Journey Builder
3. I believe you are using engagement Split and based on whether email was opened or not you are sending reminder emails. In that case, put another activity "Decision split" right after engagement split and use contact data (as it fetches the latest data available in DE) and select the above created DE and field "Available Coupon Count", then you can specify the condition like if value is > 0 then direct the contact down to this path which has the email send activity else it will route the contact to another path which will not contain any email send activity hence no email will be sent out.

P.S. - The update on DE has to be on real time otherwise, it is highly likely that DE is being refreshed after reminder email is sent.